# Change of variables using local approximation

Tags: proof-explanation, fake-proofs, change-of-variable

Let $$ T(u, v, w)=x(u, v, w) \hat{i}  +y(u, v, w)\hat{j} + z(u, v, w)\hat{k}$$
be a continuously differentiable bijection.

Then $$  \int \int \int_D f(x, y, z) dx dy dz=\int \int \int _D f \circ T(u, v, w) \det{J} du dv dw, $$
where $$ J=\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}
\end{matrix}\right]. $$

The main goal is to show that $$ \Delta V= \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z = \det{J} \Delta u \Delta v \Delta w .$$

**Attempt of proof:**

Using local approximation we get
$$\Delta T \approx J \left[\begin{matrix}
\Delta u\\
\Delta v\\
\Delta w
\end{matrix}\right]  \\
\left[\begin{matrix}
\Delta x\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)\\
\Delta y\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)\\
\Delta z\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)
\end{matrix}\right]\approx\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
\Delta u\\
\Delta v\\
\Delta w
\end{matrix}\right] \\
\left[\begin{matrix}
\Delta x\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)\\
\Delta y\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)\\
\Delta z\left(u{,}\ v{,}\ w\right)
\end{matrix}\right]\approx\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Delta u+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\Delta v+\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\Delta w\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Delta u+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\Delta v+\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\Delta w\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\Delta u+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\Delta v+\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\Delta w
\end{matrix}\right]$$

So now if we read row by row $$ \Delta x= \dots, \Delta y= \dots, \ \mathrm{and \ so \ on}, $$ and calculate $$  \Delta V= \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z,$$ we end up in a different result. So why doesn't it work using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think your attempt is fine, the only thing that you need to formalize is what "$\approx$" means, and what it means is that you choose on Taylor series up to first derivative.

Here is a simpler way to not make all the computations.
It should be easier (and equivalent) to see $T$ one component at a time, that is, verify this three cases: $$T(u,v,w)=x(u,v,w)\hat{i}+u\hat{j}+w\hat{k}$$
$$T(u,v,w)=u\hat{i}+y(u,v,w)\hat{j}+w\hat{k}$$
$$T(u,v,w)=u\hat{i}+v\hat{j}+z(u,v,w)\hat{k}$$
And by symmetry, it is enough to show only one, choose the first one.

In this case
$$J=\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\end{matrix}\right]=
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
Hence, $$\Delta x =\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Delta u +\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \Delta v +\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \Delta w, \quad \Delta y=\Delta v,\quad \Delta z=\Delta w $$

Finally, $$\Delta V=\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z\approx \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Delta u +\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \Delta v +\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \Delta w\right)\Delta v \Delta w \approx \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Delta u\Delta v \Delta w =\operatorname{det}J \Delta u \Delta v \Delta w$$

Where terms of second order ($\Delta v^2$ and $\Delta w^2$) vanish in our approximation.

Comment: thanks! But I don't think that my attempt produces the correct answer, I have tried to compute it with my calculator. And about your proof, what do you mean by saying that Δv^2 vanishes? How exact/rigorous is that?